# How can I get the data in the link? And why is the request not showing the full content of the page?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use python to extract data from an online database but I have to go over the terms and condition page to have access. I used request to log in but the output does not show the full content of the page. How can I pass the agreement page and have access to the data that showed in the page source but didn't show in the soup object I created?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://apps.usp.org/app/worldwide/medQualityDatabase/reportResults.html?country=Ethiopia%2BGhana%2BKenya%2BMozambique%2BNigeria%2BCambodia%2BLao+PDR%2BPhilippines%2BThailand%2BViet+Nam%2BBolivia%2BColombia%2BEcuador%2BGuatemala%2BGuyana%2BPeru&period=2017%2B2016%2B2015%2B2014%2B2013%2B2012%2B2011%2B2010%2B2009%2B2008%2B2007%2B2006%2B2005%2B2004%2B2003&conclusion=Both&testType=Both&counterfeit=Both'

payload = {'username':'user', 
           'password': 'pass', 
           'agree': '', 
           'edit-submit':'Submit'}
s = requests.session()
s.post(url,data = payload)

r = s.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(data)
```